# Reducing the necessary codes for describing a nested collection in C#

Tags: c#, python

I am coming from python and in that language we can define and describe a data structure very efficiently with the least amount of coding. I have this structure in python:

```
candidates = {
    "name": [
        [
            {"tag": "id", "pattern": "(.+)"},
        ],
    ],
}
```

I tried to define the same structure in C# and reached to this:

```
var candidates = new Dictionary<string, List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>()
{
    {
        "name", new List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>()
        {
            new List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
            {
                new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"tag", "id"},
                    {"pattern", "(.+)"},
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The C# version is expressive but it is really lengthy especially if I want to add multiple elements like the above to the `candidates`. Is there any other way to define the same structure but with less code?

Comment: If you want type safety, use C#. If your only design goal is “less code”, use Python. C# offers nothing you care about. Don’t use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Python expert, but I think you do not compare the same thing. You compare static typing to, well, dynamic typing (dynamic typing does not imply using type that is named dynamic, which makes the situation a bit confusing). In C# you can do something like this:

```
public class L : List<object> { }
public class D : Dictionary<string, object> { }

var candidates = new D
{
    ["name"] = new L
    {
        new L
        {
            new D
            {
                ["tag"] = "id",
                ["pattern"] = "(.+)"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

It is not as compact as your first example, but getting closer. The question is, why. What is the point of defining such structured data in code? Just define it as a string in any format you like - xml, json,... and use a library to load them into object representation.

Comment: I think you nailed it. That's the absolute minimum the code can be take to by moving away from static typing nature - and complying to Python equialent (and author's original C# code).

Answer (score 2):

Foreword: the below adds some strong typization to your code while aiming to be less verbose, so it's not directly answers "how to easier initialize internal collections".

In C#, we do have a feature of [anonymous types](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-anonymous-type): the class that compiler creates for you based on your definition.

Strictly speaking:

```
var cl = new { tag = "id"};
```

create variable named cl, that is pointing to object of class that was automatically generated to you by C# and has property "tag"; this object will have tag property set to "id" value.

It does imposes limitations though. For instance, adding new property , like this:

```
var cl2 = new { tag = "id", pattern = "..."};
```

Will generate new class behind cl2 variable for you. You can't put cl and cl2 variables to same strongly typed List or Array, thus you will loose the power of strongly typed language, will loose velocity of coding.

Did not really understood the data structure you're aiming for, but that might be close:

```
var candidates = new []
        {
            new {
                name = "candidate a",
                data = new
                    {
                        tag = "id",
                        pattern = "(.+)"
                    }
            },
            new
            {
                name =  "candidate b",
                data = new
                {
                    tag = "whatever",
                    pattern = "whatever"
                }
            }
        };

        var result = candidates.Single(o => o.name == "candidate a");
```

but I can't say this is good and flexible example of C# coding. And, of course, the lookup for candidate by "name" will not be as fast as if you would look it in Dictionary, some readings on this topic: http://net-informations.com/faq/general/dictionary-list.htm

Anyhow, on "behind" this will create 2 classes for you: one is for holding "the candidate", and one is for holding "data in that candidate" + it will create new array of "candidates" type, filled with defined "candidate" elements.

You can also combine your efforts with [dynamics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) - but that's an absolute trade off in terms of performance, IDE support and amount of errors you'll potentially have. Better don't.

Again, anonymous types impose a lot of limitations while giving some extent of flexibility.

Also, I would not try mapping/comparing features of Python to C# - both of them are great languages; one is powerfull in one field, while other has different strong sides.

As for me, I would properly organize data types structures for the code initially (define correct structs and types I will later use), to fully harness the power that C#, .NET and my IDE can offer.

**It's always a trade between verbosity, readability, speed and memory footprint - and it's up to you which way to go.**

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; my actual code is in python (because of less verbosity  compared to C#) but I was curious about the opportunities in C#.

Comment: @wiki you're welcome. I know it's not direct answer to your question but razer some approaches/considerations I would probaly look into as C# developer while porting Python app to C#. And yes, verbosity Is our curse :)...

Answer (score 0):

You’re right. C# will be really verbose compared to python... that’s not even considering the super powers of the python dictionary. While both use the term dictionary on both languages... the usage and limitations are way different.

The classic  C# approach to what you’re wanting is to have a class called candidate with properties named as name, tag, pattern etc, then a list to contain all candidates.

```
public class Candidate { public string Name; public string Pattern; public string Tag; }
```

Then....

```
var candidates = new List<Candidate>();
```

You can then use LINQ to query the list.

```
var coolCandidates = candidates.Where(m=> m.Tag == “COOL”).ToList();
```

Side note: C# list can only contain multiple instances of something but constrained to a single type (e.g. all string, all ints, all Candidate) in a list...so querying is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your class is not representative of my data structure; If you check my C# code, Candidate is a dictionary that contains a list of list of dictionaries but what you've define is a collection of objects that only have string properties.

Comment: Yes. You’ve just pointed out another difference between python in C#... strong vs dynamic typing (C# has dynamic typing but nowhere near as powerful as python). C# forces you to say “this-type-has-property-a, property-b” vs python where you add a property without requiring a type. You’re outer list didn’t have a name so I couldn’t represent it.